# Removing purchased ringtones from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ringtones

I purchased ringtones from Apple when I had my iPhone 6s. When I bought a new iPhone 8 Plus, everything as expected transferred to my new iPhone, so my ringtones are in Settings app → Sounds & Haptics. I wish to remove the purchased ringtones.

I chatted with Apple Support and they suggest I back up new iPhone and reset to factory settings to get rid of the custom ringtones.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Backing up and restoring your iPhone would restore the ringtones again, and thus is a pointless exercise.

Connect your iPhone to a Mac/PC with iTunes installed. Select you iPhone in the toolbar, locate your iPhone under Devices in the sidebar and click on Tones. You'll should be able to locate the purchased and custom ringtones.

[image]

Select the desired ringtones to remove, right click and select **Delete from Library** option in the context menu.

[image]

You'll be prompted to confirm your action. Click on Delete button to complete deleting downloaded and custom ringtones that were installed on you iPhone.

[image]